# basic sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables and columns

```
table 1: student answers
columns: question_id, student_answer,student_id,test_id
table 2: questions
columns: question_id,correct answer
```

I have to list the questions in tests that are ansewerd incorrectly by more than 30% of students.
I have gotten as far as listing the questions and the percentage fail rate of each questions.
how do I only list the questions that are answered incorrectly by more than 30% of students.

```
select q.question_id,count(student_id)*100/
(select count(distinct student_id)from student_answers ) 
       as "Percentage Student Fail Rate"
from student_answers s,questions q
where q.question_id=s.question_id 
and
correct_answer<>student_answer
group by q.question_id;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the answer using `HAVING` operator:

```
select q.question_id,count(student_id)*100/
(select count(distinct student_id)from student_answers ) 
       as "Percentage Student Fail Rate"
from student_answers s,questions q
where q.question_id=s.question_id 
    and correct_answer<>student_answer
group by q.question_id
having count(student_id)*100/(select count(distinct student_id)from student_answers ) > 30
```

Comment: the 'having' works perfectly.. I was saying having percentage student fail rate>25. I realise now you cannot query the table alias. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a subquery, and also that you do not use special characters in the names of columns.  Having to escape column names is awkward:

```
select sq.*
from (select q.question_id,
             count(student_id)*100/(select count(distinct student_id)from student_answers ) as PercentageStudentFailRate
      from student_answers s join
           questions q
           on q.question_id=s.question_id 
      correct_answer<>student_answer
      group by q.question_id
     ) sq
where PercentageStudentFailRate > 0.3;
```

Having said that (and fixed the query so it has explicit joins.  I would recommend that you use conditional aggregation for the query:

```
select sq.*
from (select q.question_id,
             avg(case when correct_answer <> student_answer then 1.0 else 0 end)*100 as PercentageStudentFailRate
      from student_answers s join
           questions q
           on q.question_id=s.question_id 
      correct_answer<>student_answer
      group by q.question_id
     ) sq
where PercentageStudentFailRate > 30.0;
```

This eliminates the need for the subquery.